# C# integers are not adding successfully to list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a system which includes adding integers to list box. However, when I am inputting a number into the text box and then clicking 'insert integer' the integer is not adding to the list box and the error message is being displayed instead saying 'number already exists in file'. This is my code for the Add integer button -

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int acceptedNum = 0;
    if (txtInsert.Text != "")
    {
        if (lstIntegers.Items.Contains(txtInsert.Text))
        {
            if (!(int.TryParse(txtInsert.Text, out acceptedNum) && acceptedNum < 0 || acceptedNum >= 100))
            {
                lstIntegers.Items.Add(txtInsert.Text);
                txtInsert.Clear();
                txtInsert.Focus();
                bubbleSort();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                txtInsert.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number already exists in list", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    if (lstIntegers.Items.Count == 30)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of entries exceeded", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        //button enabled was false however couldn't then add another 
        btnInsert.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

any suggestions?? 
thank you

Comment: I would suggest setting some breakpoints and stepping thru the code first using the debugger. change this `if (txtInsert.Text != "")` line to the following as well `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInsert.Text))`

Comment: check you logic on this line also `if (!(int.TryParse(txtInsert.Text, out acceptedNum) && acceptedNum < 0 || acceptedNum >= 100))` your accepted number will never be less than 0, you initialized it to 0

Comment: you could also check the value of the Textbox.Text before even going into or using `int.TryParse` 
read up on the following also Enumerable.Range()` method
`int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsert.Text);`
`if (Enumerable.Range(1,100).Contains(x){do your logic }`

Comment: you can do this with less code if you use `return` in your code properly as well `else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100"` put a `txt.Insert.Focus()` then add `return` to jump out of your checks otherwise you will be scratching your head for a long time to come..

Answer (score 0):

Haley I have shown you something that you can add to avoid having to do all the checks, If you are checking something in a conditional statement for example, if the txtInsert.Text; is empty, check that first, then return; if you are learning and starting out, it's not bad to create individual `if(){} statements` for readability. look at how I made changes and pay attention to the new things I added, use C# MSDN documentation for the examples and explanation. I hope this helps.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInsert.Text))
    {
        if (lstIntegers.Items.Contains(txtInsert.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number already exists in list", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            txtInsert.Text = string.Empty;
            txtInsert.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var x = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsert.Text);
            if (Enumerable.Range(1,100).Contains(x))
            {
                lstIntegers.Items.Add(txtInsert.Text);
                txtInsert.Clear();
                txtInsert.Focus();
                bubbleSort();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                txtInsert.Text = string.Empty;
                txtInsert.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please input value between 1-100", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        txtInsert.Text = string.Empty;
        return;
    }

    if (lstIntegers.Items.Count == 30)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of entries exceeded", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        //button enabled was false however couldn't then add another 
        btnInsert.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line be NOT so that the item is added if it does NOT exist?

```
if (lstIntegers.Items.Contains(txtInsert.Text))
```